# Navigation component - What is the mechanism behind for UI elements to retain their state?

Tags: android, android-navigation

When using Android Navigation Component, if we tap on the bottom view to switch away, and then switch back to the same fragment, we will have the following observation.

- A fragment will be destroyed, and then re-created again. The constructor of the fragment will be called again.

However, if there are UI elements, with assigned id in the fragment, we can also have the following observation. The state of the UI elements will be preserved. For examples

- A `RecyclerView` is able to retain its previous scroll position.
- An `EditText` is able to retain its previous text content.

May I know, what is the working mechanism behind, such that those UI elements with assigned id, is able preserve and retain their state?

Comment: You see the exact same thing when your activity goes through a configuration change (fragments are destroyed, but their state is not). What makes you think there is anything different going on?

Comment: What make me puzzle is what technique navigation component is using to achieve similar behaviour as configuration change? When we perform "normal" fragment creation/ destroy operation via `getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(fragment)` and `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment)`, we aren't sure how to achieve configuration change behaviour. Hence, would like to understand the mechanism to achieve so.

Comment: Well yeah, those would remove the fragment from the FragmentManager entirely. Did you already read the [blog post](https://link.medium.com/Rl3E0fq2sAb)?

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look on the blog post.